# How to filter based on a StructuredQuery using VDM queryhelper

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We have a VDM helper class as below

```
MmpurReqFluentHelper helper = (MmpurReqFluentHelper) valueHelpService.getAllMmpurReq();

helper.filter(FilterExpressionHelper<>);
```

How can we convert a given StructuredQuery containing filters (structure attached in the picture) into a FilterExpressionHelper<> required by the helper class as given in the above line?

[image: StructuredQuery structure]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** There actually is a convenience API:

```java
final StructuredQuery query;
final MmpurReqFluentHelper helper;

ValueBoolean filter = query.getFilters().stream().reduce(ValueBoolean::and).orElse(null);
helper.filter(new UncheckedFilterExpression<>(filter));
```

---

It's not expected to use classes from [Generic OData Client](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generic-untyped-odata-client) API (`StructuredQuery`) on the [OData V2/V4 VDM](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java) API (`MmpurReqFluentHelper`). However you can apply the following workaround:

```java
final StructuredQuery query;
final MmpurReqFluentHelper helper;

helper.filter(new FilterExpressionHelper<EntityT>() {
    @Override
    @Nullable
    FilterExpression toLegacyFilterExpression() {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    @Override
    @Nullable
    ValueBoolean toClientFilterExpression() {
        return query.getFilters().stream().reduce(ValueBoolean::and).orElse(null);
    }
});
```

Please replace `EntityT` with the respective entity type reference.

Comment: consider moving the edit to the top for visibility ;)